# Is there anything wrong with passing a message to the user using a query parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, in my node JavaScript application, I use the query parameters that you can pass to a route to display a message to the user.

For instance, I may redirect the user after an operation to `/profile?message=Profile Updated` and pass `req.query.message` into my view and display the message.

Is there anything inherently wrong with this approach for handling messages to the user? I like this approach as it doesn't require any additional modules and dependencies to work.

Comment: it will make bookmarking and "visited" marking harder. Why not just render in on the page you are showing

Comment: I wouldn't paste anything from the querystring directly into the page: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/75958/does-injecting-querystring-values-directly-into-html-pose-a-security-risk/75962 people could then use your page to create a phishing scam or inject other things into it

Comment: Encode the message you're passing some way so it no longer contains spaces, since spaces aren't valid in urls. Anyways, this is what query strings and hash fragments are supposed to do, pass parameters through the url. So there's nothing inherently wrong with it if the parameters are sanitized correctly. It just might not be appropriate depending on the rest of the code. For example, I assume this is a multipage application, since in a single page app you would just use app state to pass around values. In a multipage app though, I would sanitize and populate the message on the server already.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was pretty sceptical about the way I'm going about things and will now look into changing the current implementation to address these points.